# Curiosity: What does progn stands for?

Tags: functions

According to Emacs documentation:

```
progn is a special form in `C source code'.

(progn BODY...)

Eval BODY forms sequentially and return value of last one.
```

1. What does `progn` stands for (or its origin)?
2. Useage: Is it equivalent to `Clojure`'s `->` macro?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. `progn` is a special form borrowed from CL-like Lisp dialects. In their implementations it's composed from multiple `prog`s, expressions that are evaluated and a number that specifies which expression value is returned. `prog1` for instance evaluates all expressions and returns the value of the first, `prog2` evaluates all expressions and returns the value of the second, `progn` evaluates all expressions and returns the n'th, or rather, the last expression's value.
2. `progn` in Emacs Lisp is the equivalent of Clojure's `do` which is used as means to bundle multiple expressions into a single one.  You'll need to use it for Clojure's `if` conditional for instance.

Comment: Good answer, I upvoted it.  However, for the sake of formality: you don't really *need* it for conditionals, `cond` has an implicit `progn`.

Comment: Uh, I was speaking of Clojure which does not have implicit `progn` in its `if`.

Comment: Emacs also has `prog1` and `prog2` as built-in special forms.

Comment: I have seen this used in a lot of users' configurations. Is there a performance boost from "bundling" multiple expressions this way as opposed to evaluating them one after the other outside of `progn`?

Comment: Not sure what makes you think that.  `progn` is the equivalent of a braced block in a C-like language...