# Emacs Lisp: let with while

Tags: let-binding

I am trying to search backwards and find `[` but skip all square brackets within strings. I came across `(nth 3 (syntax-ppss))`; but I can't figure out how to use it with `let` in the following code:

```el
(defun ext-ess-symbol-at-point-modified ()
  "Return the name of a symbol to the left of \"[\"."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((cpoint (point))
           (sbt0 (search-backward "[" 1 t))
           (sbt1 (search-forward "]" cpoint t)))
      (if (and sbt0 (not sbt1))
          (progn (goto-char (1- sbt0))
                 (message "%s" (buffer-substring
                                (search-backward-regexp "^\\|[[:space:]]")
                                sbt0)))
        (error "Could not find open square bracket \"[\"")))))
```

I would like something along the lines of

```el
(let* ((cpoint (point))
       (sbt0 (while (nth 3 (syntax-ppss))
               (search-backward "[" 1 t)))
```

Comment: Just to address your title - `while` always returns `nil`, so if you want to subsequently return something else you need to place the loop within some other construct, e.g. `let`/`progn`/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like something along the lines of
>
> ```
> (let* ((cpoint (point))
>        (sbt0 (while (nth 3 (syntax-ppss))
>                (search-backward "[" 1 t)))
> ```

As Basil pointed out, you're looking for `progn`, e.g.:

```
(let* ((cpoint (point))
       (sbt0 (progn (while (nth 3 (syntax-ppss))
                      (search-backward "[" 1 t))
                    (point)))
```

---

> Actually, I was wondering if there is a function that will get the
>   location of the open square bracket to the left (even if it is on
>   lines above). For example the first `[` in
>
> `data2[col1 %in% data1[grepl("[[:num:]]+", some_col), another_col], point_here]`

Try `syntax-ppss`: `(goto-char (car (last (nth 9 (syntax-ppss)))))`

(Avoiding `wrong-type-argument` when point is not within any brackes left as an exercise for the reader.  Also, skipping over non-square parens.)

```
(syntax-ppss &optional POS)

Parse-Partial-Sexp State at POS, defaulting to point.
The returned value is the same as that of ‘parse-partial-sexp’ [...]
```

---

```
(parse-partial-sexp FROM TO &optional TARGETDEPTH STOPBEFORE OLDSTATE
COMMENTSTOP)

[...]    
Value is a list of elements describing final state of parsing:
 [...]
 9. List of positions of currently open parens, outermost first.
```

Comment: Thanks! I've written something that seems to work fine (no the code in my answer) but looked rather cumbersome. I will try to re-write using your advice above. Thanks again for the pointers!

Comment: I had checked whether a point was outside any brackets with: `(< (nth 0 (syntax-ppss)) 1)`.

Comment: @A.Blizzard Switching syntax tables is possible, but you have to be careful about the `syntax-ppss` cache getting messed up (e.g., [Bug#29710](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29710)). I would recommend looping over the `(reverse (nth 9 (syntax-ppss)))` list until you reach a square bracket instead.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way to go. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally written this

```el
(defun ext-ess-symbol-at-point-modified ()
  "Get the name of a symbol to the left of '[' from inside '[ ]'."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((cpoint (point))
          (sbt0 (search-backward "[" 1 t)))
      (while (nth 3 (syntax-ppss))
        (setq sbt0 (search-backward "[" 1 t)))
      (setq sbt1 (search-forward "]" cpoint t))
      (when (and sbt1 (nth 3 (syntax-ppss)))
        (let (anynill)
          (while (not anynill)
            (setq sbt1 (search-forward "]" cpoint t))
            (unless (and sbt1 (nth 3 (syntax-ppss)))
              (setq anynill t)))))
      (if (and sbt0 (not sbt1))
          (message "%s" (buffer-substring
                          (+ (search-backward-regexp "[^[:alnum:]_.]") 1) sbt0))                             
        (error "Couldn't find open square bracket '['")))))
```

Not sure whether it's the best way. Couldn't figure out how to do it inside `let`.

Actually, I was wondering if there is a function that will get the location of the open square bracket to the left (even if it is on lines above). For example the first `[` in

`data2[col1 %in% data1[grepl("[[:num:]]+", some_col), another_col], point_here]`

when the cursor is on `point_here`. And if inside square brackets of `data1` then it will find the bracket in `data1[`. I would have thought there would be a ready function for finding open brackets?!