# How to copy text without losing selection?

Tags: region, kill-ring

When I copy some selected text (`kill-ring-save` with `M-w`), I automatically lose my selection. I have tried with Transient Mark Mode with no luck. (Note that I'm *not* using CUA Mode.)

Comment: I initially thought it was about the X selection (in which case the variable `select-active-regions` would be relevant), but it seems to be about highlighting the region.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best solution is using `C-x C-x` to reactivate the mark.
But if you want to really keep the selection you can use:

```el
(defun copy-keep-highlight (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (prog1 (kill-ring-save beg end)
    (setq deactivate-mark nil)))
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a piece of advice like this : ```(defun yf/no-deactivate-mark (&rest _) (setq deactivate-mark nil))
(advice-addadvice-add 'kill-ring-save :after #'yf/no-deactivate-mark)```

Comment: @djangoliv, thanks. What is this `prog1`?

Comment: @YoungFrog, thanks, but your code doesn't work as its got a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Ah, copy paste error : `advice-add` should be there only once. I can't edit the comment.

Comment: @NVaughan here a good explanation: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5829/curiosity-what-does-progn-stands-for

Comment: @YoungFrog, nice answer. You could pose it as such here.